# Why isn't this vertical centring trick working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to centre three divs vertically inside another div vertically. I'm trying the technique [described here on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) and [demonstrated here](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gsodI): to add a pseudo-element :before the container:

```
.author-page-box:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}
```

and give the child divs a vertical align of middle:

```
.aub-img,
.aub-main,
.aub-contact-links {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But my attempt to make this work doesn't work! Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andfinally/aCv9e/4/)).

====================

Edit:

Here's what my layout looks like, not vertically centred!

[image]

Comment: I'm having a little trouble pinpointing *why*, but your before element has no height.  It is a lot easier to spot when you add a border to it:  http://jsfiddle.net/aCv9e/10/

Comment: Hm, you're right cimmanon, weird! When I add a specific height to it everything centres.

Comment: Whenever you use a percentage height, you must ask yourself "percentage of what, exactly?" In this, case you're try to use the percentage of a box without a height set, only a min-height. That doesn't work in CSS. The box must have an explicitly set height on the container to use percentage heights

Comment: Ahhhhhh! Thanks Alochi, that makes it clear. When I add an explicit height to .author-page-box it centres. I'm surprised the 100% doesn't take account of the container's min-height.

Comment: @Alohci Yes, but the parent element *does* have a height, it is just implicit (the height of its children).

Comment: @cimmanon - The [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property) says that for percentage heights " If the height of the containing block is not **specified explicitly** (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'." i.e. if the parent element's height is "just implicit" then the percentage of that height won't work.

Comment: Thanks Alohci, this is the key to my whole problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? [Vertically Centered Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aCv9e/9/)

You had the right idea but were adding

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to the wrong divs.

Comment: Thanks CJdriver, this seems to be the answer!